# Stops checking for changes to a file after a random duration

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on digital signage for the hospital I work using Tkinter. It updates patients on what the current delay is by reading the contents of a text file that's saved to a shared network drive and edited from a different computer to reflect the current delay.

After trialling it today the feedback has been that after a seemingly random duration it stops updating the delay  to reflect what's saved in the text file. The only way to fix it is to close and reopen. I'm struggling to recreate the issue on my own computer so I'm beginning to suspect that it may be caused by a temporary loss of connection to the network.

I'm assuming it's the following function that's causing the problem. I'm more than happy to post the rest of the code too if it's helpful.

```
def check_delay(self):
    for name in self.label_id_list:
        index = self.label_id_list.index(name)
        location = self.label_name_list[index]
        path = os.path.join("config", f"{location}.txt")
        try:
            with open(path, "rt") as in_file:
                contents = in_file.read()
                if not contents or contents == "0":
                    name.config(text=f"{location.title()} is on time", foreground="green",
                                font=("", fontSize, "bold"))
                elif contents.isdigit():
                    name.config(text=f"{location.title()} is {contents} minutes delayed", foreground="red",
                                font=("", fontSize, "bold"))
                elif 'service' in contents:
                    name.config(text=f"{location.title()} is being serviced", foreground="red",
                                font=("", fontSize, "bold"))
                else:
                    name.config(text=f"null", foreground="black",
                                font=("", fontSize, "bold"))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            open(f"config/{location}.txt", 'w')
    self.after(1000, self.check_delay)
```

EDIT:
Okay I've just managed to recreate it at home by running it from a network drive and deliberately losing connection. What I don't understand is why it doesn't just continue once it regains connection.

Comment: Is the process still running when it reportedly isn't updating any more? The first steps seems to be determining if this is an issue with your script/library or the shared network drive.

Comment: Yeah it's still running when it fails to continue updating. When it's reopened it shows the correct delay instantly too so even if it lost connection at some point it's must only be briefly. From what I can tell it should resume updating when it regains network connection.

Comment: This isn't relevant to your file reading problem, but you can make that loop more efficient. Instead of looking up the index of the current name, just do `for index, name in enumerate(self.label_id_list):`.

Comment: I'm concerned about `except FileNotFoundError: open(f"config/{location}.txt", 'w')`. So if you don't find the file you open a new empty one, which you don't explicitly close. It does get closed eventually, when the current run of `check_delay` exits, but that could take a while, since it's in the `for` loop. And having a write lock on a file can interfere with other processes attempting to write to that file.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I really appreciate it. I've removed the section you mentioned completely because it no longer serves much of a purpose. I've also added enumerate to my list of things to study further. I've identified that it is in fact caused by a loss of connection and posted a fresh question that's a little more specific to the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935895/error-handling-to-ensure-files-are-still-accessible